# Excel formula for dates in multiple columns = task complete

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to create a formula in excel to show a specific milestone is complete.

Is there a task I can use that takes multiple cells that have dates (not in a range), and marks the milestone complete? I can't seem to figure it out.

For example:

This is a basic capture of what I am looking to do.

[image]

Comment: so if all three have dates then it is complete?  Is the other option blank cells?

Comment: Yes, if the task isn't complete, the cell would be blank.

Comment: Use COUNTBLANK?

Answer (score 0):

@kc1996 if i follow correct this might help. =IF(COUNTA(A2:C2)<=3,"Completed","").. This is under the assumption that you need all three tasks to be be completed. If two tasks are completed it will return a blank. you can always change the range within the COUNTA to reference cells eg. COUNTA(A2,C2, D2)